# Finding an item which ends with jpg in a list

Tags: python, list, element

I want to find items in a list which ends with `jpg`, `png` or similar image types.

Lets say this is my list:

```
['http://www.ragalahari.com/index.aspx', 'http://www.ragalahari.com/index.aspx', 'http://www.ragalahari.com/news.aspx', 'http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/feb2015/photosessions/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock1t.jpg', 'http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/feb2015/photosessions/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock2t.jpg', 'http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/feb2015/photosessions/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock3t.jpg', 'http://www.ragalahari.com/images/facebookicon.png', 'http://www.ragalahari.com/images/searchicon.png']
```

I want to find URLS which ends with `jpg` or `png`.

My code up to here:

```
href_links = []
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):

    href = a.get('href')
    href = urljoin(link1, href)
    href_links.append(href)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
images = [x for x in href_links if x.endswith(('jpg', 'png'))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin string [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) method.

```
your_list = ["http://www.ragalahari.com/index.aspx",
"http://www.ragalahari.com/index.aspx",
"http://www.ragalahari.com/news.aspx",
"http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/feb2015/photosessions/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock1t.jpg",
"http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/feb2015/photosessions/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock2t.jpg",
"http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/feb2015/photosessions/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock3t.jpg",
"http://www.ragalahari.com/images/facebookicon.png",
"http://www.ragalahari.com/images/searchicon.png"]

img_links = []
for a in your_list:
    if a.endswith('png') or a.endswith('jpg'):
        img_links.append(a)

print img_links
```

result =

```
['http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/feb2015/photosessions/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock1t.jpg', 'http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/feb2015/photosessions/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock2t.jpg', 'http://imgcdn.raagalahari.com/feb2015/photosessions/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock/shraddha-das-in-long-black-frock3t.jpg', 'http://www.ragalahari.com/images/facebookicon.png', 'http://www.ragalahari.com/images/searchicon.png']
```